# Zend redirect within view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-redirect

Hi i have a following script to redirect within view helper

```
<?php
class Application_View_Helper_ExistUserRev extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract{

    public function existUserRev($params,$user)
    {
            $businessReviewMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessReviewsMapper();
            $businessReviewModel = new Application_Model_BusinessReviews();
        $result = $businessReviewMapper->userReviewStatus($user>getUserId(),$params['bzid']);
            if($result){
            $url = 'http://www.akrabat.com';
            $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl($url);
                    }
        }
}
?>
```

But it seems that my above redirect seems not working. How can i redirect within view helper of my  zend app? Thanks

Comment: What's the version of Zend Fw that you're using ?

Comment: @JBRTRND version if not mistaken 1.6 and above

Answer (score 3):

As you're in a View Helper class, you can't use `$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl($url);`, this is an Action Controller function.

You have to call the redirector in your View Helper.

Try this :

```
$_redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$_redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Redirector](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) is a controller ACTION helper, not a View helper, so you should use it from the controller, not from the view.

To redirect from the view (not a good idea BTW, the logic should stay in the controller, not in the view), try using the [Zend Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is even simpler then presented so far:

*Excerpt from Zend Framework 1.x reference:* [Writing Custom Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom)

> In general, the class should not echo or print or otherwise generate
>   output. Instead, it should return values to be printed or echoed. The
>   returned values should be escaped appropriately.

Basically a view helper should return a value, not perform an action.

[Action helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) on the other hand can do pretty much anything you need done.

Here is a very simple example to demonstrate the form of using the `direct()` method in the helper:

```
<?php
/**
 * Simply returns a search form to a placeholder view helper
 *
 */
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Search extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @param string $action
     * @param string $label
     * @param string $placeHolder
     * @return \Application_Form_Search
     */
    public function direct($action, $label = null, $placeHolder = null)
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Search();
        $form->setAction($action);
        $form->search->setLabel($label);
        $form->query->setAttribs(array(
            'placeholder' => $placeHolder,
            'size'        => 20,
        ));
        return $form;
    }
}
```

here is how it's used in a controller to populate a placeholder helper in either a view script or a layout.

```
 public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout()->search = $this->_helper->search(
            '/index/display', 'Search My Collection!', 'Search Query'
        );
    }
```

and in the view script or layout:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->search?>
```

In your case you might use an action helper to establish the values needed to construct the proper url, then you could pass those value to the `url()` helper or to a helper of your own construction.